# Back to previous page working in Chrome but not Safari, Any ideas?

Tags: jquery

The code i'm using is this, It works perfectly on my site on Chrome but not on Safari....

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // on click
    $('.eventitem-backlink').click(function(){
        // Go back 1 page 
        window.history.back();
    // can also use 
    // window.history.go(-1);
    });

    // on click
    $('.hack13-back-2').click(function(){
        // Go back 2 pages
        window.history.go(-2);
    });
});

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
$('.eventitem-backlink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Go back 1 page 
    window.history.back();
});
```

Comment: That didn't fix it either :/